# Initializing a struct which is a member of another struct - ISO C++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, iso

I have two structs:

```
    struct port
{
    bool isOutput;
    bool isConnected;
    int connwires;
};

struct node
{
    port p;
    vector<Wire*> w;
};
```

And I have:

```
    node *nodes;
```

in my class.
The question is how to initialize the port member (p) of all n node structs created by:

```
    nodes= new node[n];
```

statement in the class constructor.

(I was defining port struct like this:

```
    struct port
{
    bool isOutput=0;
    bool isConnected=0;
    int connwires=0;
};
```

but its invalid in "ISO C++". )

Thanks.

Comment: Default constructor (but not the compiler-provided default constructor) for `struct port`?

Comment: In-class initialization of data members is a C++11 feature. For C++03 and below, you need a constructor that initializes the data members in the *member initializer-list*.

Comment: The latter is called "in class initialization" and its allowed since C++11 for non-const static members too.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler May you explain more? I can do: 'port p=port();' in struct node, but the problem still remains unsolved, because now the node struct has an invalid initialization method!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a default constructor for `port` to initialize it's members automatically

```
struct port
{
    port() :
        isOutput(false),
        isConnected(false),
        connwires(0)
    { }

    bool isOutput;
    bool isConnected;
    int connwires;
};
```

Note that your last code is valid and does what you expect since C++11.